# find the smallest solution of an inequality function in maple

Tags: maple

an =(5 − 77 sin(n) + 8n^2)/(1 − 4n^2), L=-2
For ε =1/500, use Maple to find the smallest N such that |aN − L| < ε.

which command should I use? I have tried that:
an:=(5 − 77 sin(n) + 8n^2)/(1 − 4n^2)
solve(an+2=1/500)
and this came out a really weird answer which said root of blabla..
or I have tried minimize(an+2) and it seems wrong too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you intend for n to be a positive integer. If not then please give additional details.

Also, why do you mention both `N` and `n`? If you mean fully the same thing by both then it's not helpful to use both in your description.

One way to go about this is to find a value for `n` above which the inequality is always true. Once you know that then (if it's not huge) you can just test the positive integers below it. The answer will be 1 more than the first (of the descending values) to fail the check.

This is certainly not the only way to accomplish this in Maple.

```
an := (5-77*sin(n)+8*n^2)/(1-4*n^2):
L := -2:
eps := 1/500:
```

It seems that the `solve` command cannot handle the `sin(n)`, so we'll replace that term by a dummy name `K` on which we'll place the restriction `-1<=K<=1`.

```
Q := [solve( { subs(sin(n)=K,abs(an-L)<eps), K<=1, K>=-1, n>=1 } )]:
```

You can look at `Q` if you want. If we only need a bound then we can be rough and ready about yanking out inequalities involving `n`. Another way to go about all this is to split into two cases by the signum of `an-L`, then to replace `sin(n)` by the appropriate worst case value, and then to solve the two simpler inequalities for `n`. (You could do that by hand for this problem.)

```
R := [solve( indets(Q,{identical(n)>anything}) )];

                          [ /1      (1/2)    \ ]
                     R := [{ - 42001      < n }]
                          [ \2               / ]

upper := floor(lhs( R[1,1] ));

                            upper := 102
```

Now we know a value for n above which the inequality must hold. A quick loop over descending values of `n` tells us where the largest (integer) value of `n` violates the inequality. The answer should be 1 more than that.

```
for i from upper to 1 by -1 do
  if not is( eval(abs(an-L)<eps, n=i) ) then
    ans := i+1;
    i := 1; next;
  end if;
end do;

ans;

                          100
```

And, while a plot is no proof we can look at a plot to get a better idea of what was going on.

[image]